# Nodejs giving me download instead of html response

Tags: node.js, download, streaming, http-1.1

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express'),
      app = express.createServer(express.logger());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    var name = request.param('name', null);
    response.header('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    var t = setInterval(function(){
        response.write('Hello World by '+name+' (using http-1.1 streaming data!)<br />');
    }, 2000);
    /*request.socket.on('close', function() {
        clearInterval(t);
    }); */
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
    //clearInterval(t);

  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

I am using express because I am testing this in heroku and I used the guide there.
So when I open the app I get a download popup with the data in the file (downloaded) instead of the html (dom) response.

What did I do wrong? (is it a browser problem?)

**Edit:**
@Joe, has solved my initial problem but yet, I have two questions:
1) Why i don't need to insert a 'correct' content type? (of streaming?)
2) Why does this code out put only after along time (about half a minute).?

Comment: This might help explain what `text/event-stream` does http://dsheiko.com/weblog/html5-and-server-sent-events/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to display it as HTML you will want your `Content-Type` to be `text/html`

Comment: But how will I stream the data? in every interval lap?

Comment: & It works, but it loads for a long time (about 22 seconds) until it even shows something, why?

Comment: Does it take 22 seconds the first time, then each time after seem very quick? It could be using some development setup on boot. I don't know NodeJS well enough.

Comment: Hi @funerr, I also had to set response.header('Accept', 'text/html'), in addition to response.header('Content-Type', 'text/html')